# cannot remove from parent when the session is not locked

Tags: spring, vaadin, vaadin7

when i test my application with 2 session, in one browser all things is OK and in another one i get exception.

```
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
@PreserveOnRefresh
@SpringComponent
public class TestUI extends UI {

    @Autowired
    MainLayout content;

    @Autowired
    DetailView detailView;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        VaadinSession.setCurrent(VaadinSession.getCurrent());
        Navigator navigator = new Navigator(this, detailView);
        navigator.addView("tests", TestView.class);
        setContent(content);
    }
}
```

[image]

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot remove from parent when the session is not locked. Furthermore, there is another locked session, indicating that the component might be about to be moved from one session to another.
>       at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractSingleComponentContainer.removeFromParent(AbstractSingleComponentContainer.java:175)
>       at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractSingleComponentContainer.setContent(AbstractSingleComponentContainer.java:148)
>       at com.vaadin.ui.UI.setContent(UI.java:1312)

Comment: What are scopes of your MainLayout and DetailView?

Comment: i only anotated them with `@SpringComponent`

Comment: you need to define that scope is prototype or something else than singleton which is the default. Now same mainlayout and detailview instances are shared by all users which doesn't work.

Comment: thanks @HenriKerola i use **@UIScope** and problem solved!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When defining Vaadin components as Spring managed beans, one must define always a non-singleton scope for those. For example:

```
@Component
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class MainLayout extends VerticalLayout {
```

This is because a Vaadin component can only have one parent. Other possible scopes are `@UIScope` and `@ViewScope`.